# Alter macro from delete columns from list to format columns from list, almost working

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out how to apply the first part of the Sub (act on columns in header list) to other kind of actions (the original was set to delete columns in a list).

My attempt almost works in that it applies some simple formatting to the list: "RespID, Score"

But the Sub is only appling to the first item in the list "RespID"

The only thing I alter in the Sub is twords the bottom after the `'~~> Act on columns`

Thanks

```
Sub FormatRespIDScore360()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim ColList As String, ColArray() As String
Dim lastCol As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim boolFound As Boolean
Dim delCols As Range
Dim lastRow As Long

On Error GoTo Whoa

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set WS = Sheets("360")

ColList = "RespID, Score"

ColArray = Split(ColList, ",")

'~~> Get the last column
lastCol = WS.Cells.Find(What:=" ", After:=WS.Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
MatchCase:=False).Column

For i = 1 To lastCol
    boolFound = False
    '~~> Checking of the current cell value is present in the array
    For j = LBound(ColArray) To UBound(ColArray)
        If UCase(Trim(WS.Cells(1, i).Value)) = UCase(Trim(ColArray(j))) Then
            '~~> Match Found
            boolFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
   '~~> If not match not found
    If boolFound = True Then
        If delCols Is Nothing Then
            Set delCols = WS.Columns(i)
        Else
            Set delCols = Union(delCols, WS.Columns(i))
        End If
    End If
Next i

'~~> Act on columns
If Not delCols Is Nothing Then

    With Sheets(1)
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, delCols.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    End With


    With Sheets(1).Range(delCols, WS.Cells(lastRow, delCols.Column))

            .NumberFormat = "0"
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
            .WrapText = False
            .Orientation = 0
            .AddIndent = False
            .IndentLevel = 0
            .ShrinkToFit = False
            .ReadingOrder = xlContext
            .MergeCells = False

        End With

    End If
LetsContinue:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
Whoa:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This have found a rather complicated way to do something very simple! The key problem my be in the line:

```
With Sheets(1).Range(delCols, WS.Cells(lastRow, delCols.Column))
```

You actually want to apply the formatting to the columns that have certain headings - you should find out what those columns are, and apply the formatting to them.  Starting with a very simple example:

```
Dim colToFormat as Range
set colToFormat = Range("A1", "B25");

With colToFormat
    .NumberFormat = "0"
End With
```

This should be the essence of the code. Now you need to figure out what to replace `"A1"` and `"B25"` with. You already know the headings - so why not look for them on the sheet.

```
Sub fmt()
    ColList = "RespID,Score"
    colarray = Split(ColList, ",")
    Set colToFormat = Nothing
    For Each heading In colarray
    Set headingFound = Range("A:A").Offset(0, ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:=heading, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False).Column - 2)

      If colToFormat Is Nothing Then Set colToFormat = headingFound Else Set colToFormat = Union(colToFormat, headingFound)
    Next
    MsgBox colToFormat.Address

End Sub
```

Three things to note:

1. There is no space before "Score" in the `ColList`. The `Split` function will otherwise add a space in front of the name, and it will not be found unless there is an actual space in the column heading (maybe that's your fundamental problem, actually)
2. I am just showing that the correct columns are found using a MsgBox - this is not quite the same thing as figuring out what cells you want to format (but it gets you most of the way there).
3. You will have to figure out what is the last cell you want to format. If you want to format the whole column, then `With colToFormat` should work.

I think the above should help you on your way. Remember - keep your code simple, or you will not understand what you did in three months. And be very careful about using someone else's code...

Comment: Floris, Thanks for the code and the instruction I could pretty much follow your explanation. I think I will be able to use your approach much more easily to apply a list of column names to "actions" that I need to apply to my excel file.  Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it helped. Often just a nudge is all it takes. I have been there, believe me...